# JPA Specification: Select all entities which have at least one param with attribute from list

Tags: spring-data-jpa, criteria

I have 2 entities with relationship ManyToMany

```
@Entity
@Table
public class TranslationUnit implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "translationUnit", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Category implements Serializable {
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_translation_unit",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "translation_units_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<TranslationUnit> translationUnits = new HashSet<>();
}
```

In Category I have 1 field, which should be used for filtering:

```
String name;
```

I need to be able to specify list of Category names (List), and select those TranslationUnits which have at least one Category with specified name.
I have several other filtering options, which should be used together,  and I successfully built Specifications for them. But I've stuck with this one.

Please help.

P.S. One of my existing Specifications looks like this:

```
Specification idSpec = (Specification) (r, q, cb) -> {

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (!filterRequest.getTranslationUnitIds().isEmpty())
                predicates.add(r.get(TranslationUnit_.id).in(filterRequest.getTranslationUnitIds()));

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
```

Comment: Do you want CriteriaAPI or JPQL? And how do your other specifications look like?

Comment: Hey. I need CriteriaAPI. I appended my question with existing Spec. Thanks.

Comment: as i can see you already have an example with in. So what you are looking for is similar to the in predicate that you already use. Or do you want to do something else?

Comment: In my working example I select all TranslationUnits that have needed id. id is just a long value. But Category is a Set in TranslationUnit, and each Category has name. So, it's ManyToMany, and, as I said, I need to get as a result List<TranslationUnit> , that have at least one Category with a name from list provided. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. You could use IN for filtering translation units by category names list. I believe, it will look like this using Criteria API:

```
Root<TranslationUnit> itemsRoot = ...;
Join join = itemsRoot.join("categories");
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates(join.get("name").in(categoryNamesList));
```